# An identity in Zamolodchikov's $c$ theorem paper

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have seen this mentioned in various papers/lecture notes/Stack Exchange questions [1-4]:
$$\Theta = \beta^i(g) \Phi_i.$$

Here $\Theta$ is the trace of the stress tensor, $g=\{g^i\}$ is the set of all (dimensionless) coupling constants of the theory, and the fields $\Phi_i$ are defined as (following [3]):
\begin{equation}
\Phi_i(g,x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial g^i}\sigma(g,a,x)
\end{equation}
where sigma is defined as the action density, i.e. $ S(g,a) = \int \sigma(g,a,x) d\mathbf{x}$, and $a$ is a UV length cutoff.

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/537323/85693) proves this in the case of a conformal field theory. But it seems like all the other sources are stating this as a general property of RG flow. In fact Zamolodchikov [3] states: "The exact meaning of the assertion that a field theory is renormalizable is that for all g the field $\Theta$ can be expanded in (*the above mentioned*) basis: $\Theta = \beta^i(g)\Phi_i$"

---

So my questions are:

1. If this identity is true for all $g$, as Zamolodchikov states, that means that at a fixed point $g=g^*$, satisfying $\beta(g^*)=0$, we must have $\Theta=0$. But this is equivalent to conformal invariance. This line of argument can't be correct because then this would be a trivial proof of scale invariance $\implies$ conformal invariance, without any of the assumptions that usually go into the proof (e.g. Polchinski showed that we need to assume a discrete spectrum of scaling dimensions in $d=2$ in order to conclude SI $\implies$ CI). How do we reconcile this with the identity in question?
2. What is the correct way to interpret this identity and how would we go about writing a proof for the same?

---

**References**:

[1] (between eqs 5.5 and 5.6) https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0884

[2] (eq 6.50) https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04074

[3] (eq 5) Zamolodchikov, a B. 1986. “Irreversibility of the Flux of the Renormalization Group in a 2D Field Theory.” JETP Lett. 43 (1986) 730-732, Pisma Zh.Eksp.Teor.Fiz. 43 (1986) 565-567

[4] Stack exchange question: [Zamolodchikov's c-theorem paper](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143518/85693)

Comment: your assertion in 1 is correct, but the action appearing is not the classical action but the quantum effective action. this removes any discrepancies with the statements in Polchinski etc.

Comment: @Wakabaloola do you mean that the identity in question is not true as an operator equation but only as a classical equation?

Comment: all i’m saying is that the action appearing is the quantum effective action. so it’s the legendre transform of the generating function of renormalised connected greens functions. it formally contains all quantum corrections

Comment: Do you mean $\int dx \sigma(g,a,x)$ is the effective 1PI action?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: My question still stands. If that's the quantum effective action, the identity in question should be interpreted as an operator equation. At the fixed point, it will tell us that $\Theta=0$ holds as an operator equation, which is equivalent to the statement that the theory has CI. Am I missing something here?

Comment: i apologise, i think i misunderstood what you were asking. are you asking about the distinction between invariance under rigid coordinate rescalings and invariance under conf transformations? and how these differ in the eqns you wrote?

Comment: I think the main thing that I'm asking is how to derive the first equation in my question for a general point in the RG trajectory that is not a fixed point.